# Need to make Google prettyprint scroll without a max-width

Tags: html, css, pretty-print

I'm using google prettyprint to display code, the problem is that my code sections will not resize to be scrollable unless I set a max-width on them. But I can't set the max-width to the device width, at least I can't figure out how to do that.

Is there a better way to do this?

The problem is when it shows up on mobile it will be as wide as the longest line of code...